# How to add "signature impersonation" in docusign Production account without creating Organization

Tags: docusignapi

In developer docusign account we can see "Switch to" button to add "signature impersonation" permission in connected app, but when we go for Production account as we don't have any organization attached so how we can add "signature impersonation" permission for esigning on docusign API access.

Comment: Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. ***Thank you!***

Answer (score 0):

The `impersonation` scope is used with the JWT grant flow.

As you say, administrative consent requires both a DocuSign organization to be set up, and the email DNS domain must be captured.

So, in your case, use individual consent to grant consent by the person who will be impersonated. This is a one-time process per impersonated person per client ID.

Here are the details:

- [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBziZ2TfFVs)
- [Blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/oauth-jwt-granting-consent)